# What is the lastest level of ubuntu for a Dell Optiplex 620 computer

Tags: dell

I have several dual processor 3ghz Pentium D Dell 620 systems with at least 2gb of memory.  I want to move them off XP and do not want to go to  Win7.  Am I limited to 13.04 or can I go to a later release.

Comment: 1510 but it is still pretty release. Ubuntu versions are not targeted to dell hardware

Answer (score 1):

As a test, I've run Ubuntu, Lubuntu, and a whole bunch of other distos on hardware such as what you're describing. Your RAM is a little low but it should run fine - albeit not as fast as it would on more robust hardware. You may want to give Lubuntu a try as it is lighter on resources though the rest will run but not as speedy in my experience.

You can get Lubuntu here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

You can read about Lubuntu here:
http://lubuntu.net/

You can download 15.04 here:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.04/release/

You can wait a little bit (by the end of this month) and 15.10 should be released or you can find a beta version, which I'm *not recommending* but listing for completeness, here:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/